# How to print out the last item in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a program that will run through a list of integers entered, sort them from smallest to largest and then print out the last item(largest), the middle item entered and first item(smallest integer).

As you can see from the code I have the average of the items.

The "bubbleSort" Method puts them in order and prints out the sorted array.

Any suggestions?

### Code:

```
class statistics{
    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of integers you want to input?");
        int n = EasyIn.getInt();

        //declare arrey called numbers and give it the length of the number enter.
        int[] numbers = new int[n];

        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter number: " + (i+1));
            numbers[i] = EasyIn.getInt();
        }// end of for loop
        // add a switch case for the print outs and a menu.
        bubbleSort(numbers);
        System.out.println("The average is " + averageMethod(numbers));
    }// end of main method.
    public static int averageMethod(int[] nums){
        int total=0;
        int average=0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
            total = total+nums[i];
            average = total/nums.length;
        }// end of for loop
        return average;
    }// end of totalMethod

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] ar) {
        int temp;
        // this code does the bubble sort
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = ar.length -1; i>0; i--){
            for(int j=0;j<i; j++){
                if(ar[j]>ar[j+1]){
                    temp=ar[j];
                    ar[j]=ar[j + 1];
                    ar[j+1]= temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("The sorted array is : ");
            for(int b=0; b<ar.length; b++){
                System.out.print(ar[n] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } // end of buble sort
}// end of class.
```

Comment: so your sort works, but the problems is you want to print the larges, smallest and the number in the middle of the array?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the sort works but I want to then print the largest, smallest and the number in the middle of the array.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with middle of the array. As an even sized array does not have something like a middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an ascending sorted array `arr` of length `n`, the smallest element is found at `arr[0]` and the largest at `arr[n - 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to what Smutje said, to get the middle item:
if n is odd then it will be `arr[(n/2)+1]`, but if n is even then it depends on what you considre "middle", take this for example:
if n=4 then n/2 = 2, which is the third index, and (n-1)/2=1, which is the second index, now which one is the middle?

Answer (score 1):

To print the first, middle, and last, you could do something like this:

```
if(numbers != null && numbers.length > 0) {
    System.out.println(numbers[0]);
    System.out.println(numbers[numbers.length / 2]);
    System.out.println(numbers[numbers.length - 1]);
}
```

Another suggestion is not to use Bubble Sort :)